# How to make a Server perform Tasks behind a normal PHP / SQL Website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, server

How do i realise Tasks being calculated behind a Website, that is a normal php / Mysql Website, without being triggered by a Website user, like deleting a chat room automatical from the sql db, when the user that created it goes offline, in an simple Webchat with userchatrooms? Another example is some Text and Image based Browsergame, where every 5 Minutes (In Servertime) all Unit Movements and eventual fights between Users on a Image Based Game Map where calculated, when 2 Users or more meet on the same Map Tile? The calculated damage is sent back to the PHP / Ajax Website

Comment: You might want to take a look at [cron jobs](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/).

Answer (score 1):

To fire off tasks at an interval (ie: every five minutes) you would use a CRON job. To set that up is going to be dependent on what kind of server you're running. If you have a server GUI like CPANEL or PLESK there should be controls for setting CRON jobs. Essentially you input a time in this format

minute, hour, day, month, day of week

so 1 * * * * would run on the 1st minute of every hour, every day.

You point that to a command - probably a shell script, which will run whatever you need it to do.

To communicate that back to the "server" you would basically just update your database or whatever datastore you're using within your cron job.

So in your first example, to do something every five minutes, you would do

*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh

Then in that script, do whatever operations you need and save back to the DB.

If you are using a server admin GUI as previously mentioned, it's easiest to just hop in there and find the cron jobs tab and enter it.

If you're just managing your server with shell access you need to go put that in your crontab. The command for this might be dependent on the OS you're using but it's probably

```
crontab -e
```